# Error resizing images with Paperclip after images have been added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resize, imagemagick, paperclip

This is the code in my model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :tiny => "25x25#",
    :thumbnail => "50x50#",
    :small  => "150x150>",
    :medium => "300x300>" },
    :default_url => "/images/default_:style.jpg"
```

I run this command:

```
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=Photo
```

and I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Photo
```

What going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it doesn't know your model Photo. Try a command "require", e.g.

```
require "lib/photo"
```

or whatever your model path is.